# Is there a more elegant way to solve this Ramda filter problem？

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
var a = { id: 1, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' };
var b = { id: 2, name: 'name2', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag2' };
var c = { id: 3, name: 'name3', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' };
var d = { id: 4, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' };
var e = { id: 5, name: 'name4', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag4' };
var f = { id: 6, name: 'name5', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' };

var arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f];

var typeFind = R.curry((type, ex) => R.find(ele => ele.type === type, ex));
var tagEqProps = R.curry((o1, o2) => R.eqProps('tag', o1, o2));
var filtered = R.curry((arr, ex) => R.filter(ele => tagEqProps(ele, typeFind(ele.type, ex)), arr));

var excludes = R.filter(ele => ele.name === 'filter-name', arr);
filtered(arr, excludes);
```

I need to filter:

1. objects which name is 'filter-name'
2. objects which property 'tag' equal to 'filter-name' objects in each type

in this case, result is 1, 3, 4, 6.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [R.filter](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter) with [R.propEq](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) to get all items with the a name that is equal to `filter-name`, and pluck the tags. Then use [R.innerJoin](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin), with a list of the tags you plucked to get all items with the relevant tags:

```js
const { pipe, filter, propEq, innerJoin, pluck } = R;

const getFiltered = pipe(
  filter(propEq('name', 'filter-name')),
  pluck('tag')
);

const getByTags = arr => innerJoin(
  (record, tag) => record.tag === tag,
  arr,
  getFiltered(arr)
);

const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"filter-name","type":"type1","tag":"tag1"},{"id":3,"name":"name3","type":"type1","tag":"tag1"},{"id":4,"name":"filter-name","type":"type2","tag":"tag3"},{"id":6,"name":"name5","type":"type2","tag":"tag3"}];

const result = getByTags(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any solution to get the complement of result, I change `record.tag === tag` to `record.tag !== tag`, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a series of versions that show how one might make a point-free version of this function, with the help of some custom combinators.  At the end, though, I suggest that it's not at all worth it, that another version with an intermediate variable -- written with or without Ramda -- is significantly more readable.

### First Pass

It's fairly clear that there are two distinct steps to the problem: first, finding the tags which match the `filter-name`, and second, finding the elements which have those tag names.  Let's write functions for these:

```js
const tagNames = (filterName) => (arr) => 
  pipe (filter (propEq ('name', filterName)), pluck ('tag')) (arr)

const getItems= (propNames) => (arr) => filter (anyPass (map (propEq ('tag'), propNames))) (arr)

const matchTags = (filterName) => (arr) => 
  getItems (tagNames (filterName) (arr)) (arr)

const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 2, name: 'name2', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag2' }, { id: 3, name: 'name3', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 4, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }, { id: 5, name: 'name4', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag4' }, { id: 6, name: 'name5', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }]

console .log (matchTags ('filter-name') (arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, filter, propEq, pluck, anyPass, map} = R        </script>
```

These are straightforward uses of the relevant [Ramda functions](https://ramdajs.com/docs).  We combine the two functions into `matchTags` in a relatively simple manner.  Passing `arr` at two different points is slightly surprising, but it shouldn't be too surprising given the requirements.

### Moving Toward Point-free

When the final curried argument is used only as the call to an underlying function and that result is returned, we can simply remove the parameter and that call and get an equivalent function.  In other words, `(arg) => foo(arg)` is equivalent to `foo` for any unary function, `foo`.  This is the case for both `tagNames` and `getItems` with the parameter `arr`.  So we can simplify the above like this:

```js
const tagNames = (filterName) => 
  pipe (filter (propEq ('name', filterName)), pluck ('tag'))

const getItems = (propNames) => filter (anyPass (map (propEq ('tag'), propNames)))
```

And we can then go one step further by removing `propNames` from `getItems`:

```js
const getItems = pipe (map (propEq ('tag')), anyPass, filter)
```

You can verify that we haven't broken anything in the following snippet:

```js
const tagNames = (filterName) => 
  pipe (filter (propEq ('name', filterName)), pluck ('tag'))

const getItems = pipe (map (propEq ('tag')), anyPass, filter)

const matchTags = (filterName) => (arr) => 
  getItems (tagNames (filterName) (arr)) (arr)

const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 2, name: 'name2', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag2' }, { id: 3, name: 'name3', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 4, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }, { id: 5, name: 'name4', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag4' }, { id: 6, name: 'name5', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }]

console .log (matchTags ('filter-name') (arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, filter, propEq, pluck, anyPass, map} = R        </script>
```

### Adding Combinators

We are stuck for an easy way to make `matchTags` or `tagNames` point-free.  They use their arguments multiple times or in positions other than the very end.  We could certainly leave it like this, but we might note that there are patterns in these we might want to reuse.  One way to do this is to use [Combinators](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45).  Combinators combine simple functions into more complex ones, and many important Ramda functions act as combinators, including all the Ramda ones mentioned in that list and others such as `converge` and `useWith`.

Let's look at the structure of `matchTags`, naming the parts we see:

```js
const matchTags = (filterName) => (arr) => 
//                 `----x----'    `-y-' 
  getItems (tagNames (filterName) (arr)) (arr)
//`---f--'  `---g--' `-----x----' `-y-'  `-y-'
```

We can write a very simple function which captures that structure, and use it to build `matchTags` out of simpler parts.  There is a strong tradition of using single capital letters to name such combinators, or to use the names of certain birds.  We don't want to reuse any of those, or to make any real suggestive name for a function we're not sure is generally useful.  So for now, let's just call this functions `Z1`.  We can use it like this:

```js
const Z1 = (f) => (g) => (x) => (y) =>
  f (g (x) (y)) (y)

const matchTags = Z1 (getItems) (tagNames)
```

We have not removed any complexity -- we've just shunted it around.  We let `Z1` handle the complexity of how the functions are combined, and used it to simplify `matchTags`.  This could possibly be worth it on its own.  But if we decide that `Z1` is an important enough function that we want to reuse it and possibly give it a more descriptive name, then it definitely is worthwhile.

We could do the same thing with a slight rewrite of `tagNames`:

```js
const tagNames = (filterName) => (arr) =>
//                `----x---'     `-y-'
  pluck('tag') ((pipe (propEq ('name'), filter)) (filterName) (arr))
//`----f-----'  `--------------g--------------'   `----x---'  `-y-'
```

We can now add `Z2`, like this:

```js
const Z2 = (f) => (g) => (x) => (y) =>
  f (g (x) (y))

const tagNames = Z2 (pluck('tag')) (pipe (propEq ('name'), filter))
```

`Z2` looks more familiar. There's a good chance that this is an existing named combinator.  If we choose, we can try to find what name might be associated with this.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Combining all this, and inlining the helper functions, we could rewrite like this:

```js
const matchTags = Z1
  (pipe (map (propEq ('tag')), anyPass, filter))
  (Z2 (pluck('tag')) (pipe (propEq ('name'), filter)))
```

It still works, as shown by this snippet:

```js
const Z1 = (f) => (g) => (x) => (y) =>
  f (g (x) (y)) (y)

const Z2 = (f) => (g) => (x) => (y) =>
  f (g (x) (y))

const matchTags = Z1
  (pipe (map (propEq ('tag')), anyPass, filter))
  (Z2 (pluck('tag')) (pipe (propEq ('name'), filter)))

const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 2, name: 'name2', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag2' }, { id: 3, name: 'name3', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 4, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }, { id: 5, name: 'name4', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag4' }, { id: 6, name: 'name5', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }]

console .log (matchTags ('filter-name') (arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, filter, propEq, pluck, anyPass, map} = R        </script>
```

### Is This Worth It?

We've created two new potentially reusable combinators, and we've refactored our main code to use them and it is now point-free.  So the question is, is it worth it?

My answer?  **No!  This is horrible code!**

Even though we might find other uses for these combinators, unless we use them a great deal, we won't remember what `Z1` and `Z2` do.  Perhaps we'll find more descriptive names, and perhaps that will help.  But there's a strong chance that this will always remain a mystery.

If the requirements were so totally mysterious that any code would be complex, then this might do.  But we can do better.

### A Simpler Implementation

Writing the two steps required explicitly, with a local variable in-between to me makes the code much easier to read:

```js
const matchTags = (filterName, arr) => {
  const tags = pluck ('tag', filter (propEq ('name', filterName), arr))
  return filter (propSatisfies (includes(__, tags), 'tag'), arr)
}

const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 2, name: 'name2', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag2' }, { id: 3, name: 'name3', type: 'type1', tag: 'tag1' }, { id: 4, name: 'filter-name', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }, { id: 5, name: 'name4', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag4' }, { id: 6, name: 'name5', type: 'type2', tag: 'tag3' }]


console .log (matchTags ('filter-name', arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {__, pluck, filter, propEq, propSatisfies, includes} = R  </script>
```

Notice the variable `tags`.  That stores, in the sample case, `['tag1', 'tag3']`.  Using that makes the code feel much more like our initial pass, where the functionality was segregated by process step.

To me, this is a clean and understandable implementation.  It's not the only one, for sure.  And I would never bring in Ramda just to create a function like this, as a plain JS version is just as clean:

```js
const matchTags = (filterName, arr) => {
  const tags = arr
    .filter (({name}) => name == filterName)
    .map (({tag}) => tag)
  return arr .filter (({tag}) => tags .includes (tag))
}
```

Between them, I'm not sure whether I prefer the Ramda version or the vanilla JS one, but to my eyes either one would do.

### Lessons

Many new Ramda users seem to think that point-free is an important goal on its own.

I would suggest instead that it's simply a tool in our toolbox.  We should use it only so long as it makes our code easy to read and write.  When it obfuscates things, we should avoid it entirely.

This is a lesson I have to learn over and over.  The above chain of implementations was pretty well how I tried to solve this problem.  Even though I preach this "point-free is not for everything" idea, I still find myself slipping back into it far too often.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me a lot, I will think about the point-free scenario carefully in the future!